# WIFI not working ubuntu 16.04 in hp 15bs146tu

Tags: 16.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I owe a HP 15bs-146tu i5 8th gen Laptop and have installed ubuntu on it.! 
the network adapter is "Realtek RT8723DE 802.11B/G/N PCLe Adapter".There is no option for wifi connectivity in ubuntu.PLease help ASAP.